# sub-section margin

Tags: sectioning, margins

I'm currently trying to learn latex, and I get the following "error"
[image: The section is displayed correctly, but the sub-section no]

The section is displayed correctly, but the sub-section no(I wish that the text start on the right of the tittle.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%=====SECTION====
\titleformat{\section}% command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\Large\raggedright}%format
{\thesection.} %label
{0em}%sep
{
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\vspace{1ex}
\centering
}% before-code
[
\vspace{-0.5ex}%
\rule{\textwidth}{0.3pt}
] % after-code
\titlespacing{\section}%command
{0pc}%left
{0pc}%vertical space before title
{0pc}%separation between title and non-sectioning text
%=====SUB-SECTION====
\titleformat{\subsection}% command
[leftmargin] % shape
{\bfseries\Large}%format
{\\} %label
{0em}%sep
{
}% before-code
[
] % after-code
\titlespacing{\subsection}%command
{0pc}%left
{0pc}%vertical space before title
{0pc}%separation between title and non-sectioning text

\begin{document}
\section{Sectio1} % (fold)
\label{sec:sectio1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet tempor viverra. Etiam semper tristique magna, ut tempor nunc aliquet sit amet. 
\subsection{subsectio2} % (fold)
\label{sub:subsectio2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet tempor viverra. Etiam semper tristique magna, ut tempor nunc aliquet sit amet. 
\end{document}
```

This is how I want it :
[image]

I commented the different lines to help me, but I didn't find my mystake.
Can anyone help me ?
Thx

Comment: Why do you use the `leftmargin` shape?

Comment: Because I did read it on this web site:
http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/titlesec.pdf
Wich one should I use instead
And thx for the answer

Comment: Actually, I don't see what you try to obtain. Could you describe it more precisely? For instance do you want to have the subsection title in the left  margin?  Or should the text flow around it like a lettrine?  And should it have the same size ( \Large`) as section titles?